# Is there a named unit that, when divided by 32, gives meters per second?

Tags: mathematics, units

I am receiving unknown units of speed from another system. I must divide the value by 32 to get meters per second. What units do I use to refer to the values I'm receiving? Is there any such unit? Is this just random malice from the previous developers? Google give me nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that if you divide your numbers by 32, you get a speed in meters per second, that means that the unit for the speeds you are being given is $\frac{1}{32}\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$. There's no standard name for this unit, but that's not a problem. People use unnamed, nonstandard units all the time. In fact, that's how all our current units got started. A meter was originally defined to be a pretty much arbitrary distance, and the only reason it now has a name and is so widely used is that a bunch of people all agreed to call this particular arbitrary distance a "meter."

If it bothers you to be using a unit without a name, you can give it one. Just make a note somewhere that, say

$$1\text{ Dave} = \frac{1}{32}\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$$

and then you can write that your speeds are measured in Daves.

Here's another [post on the nature of units](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/newtons-second-law-of-motion-in-terms-of-momentum/15243#15243) that is, if not directly relevant to you, at least closely related.

Comment: I like how you name the unit after yourself.

Comment: I didn't. The unit is named after the original poster of the question.

Answer (score 8):

Dividing by 32 is equivalent to shifting by 5 bits in binary.  This number probably comes from some digital hardware which uses a fixed point binary representation for the velocity.

Comment: Yes, that is what's happening. I was just wondering why and what to call it. Thank you.