# What is the use (/ meaning) of $F =ma$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

I have noticed that [**Euler's**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_laws_of_motion#Euler.27s_first_law) formula for *force* is useful with a couple of natural forces (at distance), like gravity, that can follow a body any length.

If you consider the most common occurrences of a force, that is the so-called **push** or pull, I can see little use of that definition, I hope someone can contradict me.

Even the longest human arm can extend for less than one meter and, in that limited span of space and time, reach a modest acceleration up to 20/30m/s.

But the most striking feature of the formula $F=ma$ is that it doesn't say anything about the applied force, but can only measure its oucome. Suppose we say that a basketball player/shot putter exerts a force of 200 N for 1/4 sec, in theory that means a change of momentum of 50 kgm/s but actually we know nothing of what will really happen when a shot or a basket ball or a ping-pong ball is launched.

- we know nothing of the *energy* that was spent,
- of the *energy* the object will acquire;
- we know nothing of the change of *velocity* of the object, and
- we can't even be sure that the change of *momentum* will actually be 50, since there is a limit to the acceleration due to the max v reached by the hand/ fingertips (therefore the momentum of a ping-pong ball can be at most, say, 1 kgm/s).

Am I missing something really important, or is Euler's (*) formula rarely of great use?

**Edit**:

The question has been misinterpreted: it is neither aggressive nor too broad, but very simple. It draws the attention on the fact that in *dimensional analysis* different entities may have same units.

$F*t$ has the same units of *momentum* but cannot be totally identified with it for many reasons, one being the one I pointed out, that it carries less information than a real *momentum* J = m * v.

The simple question: "determine the velocity or Kinetic energy of an object to which a push, a so-called "impulse" J = 50 Kgm/s (F = 200 N , t = .25 sec) is given" , has not received a concrete answer, only generic, formulas.

If determining the force exerted by muscles is considered the problem, you may consider a compressed - released spring:

[image]

- The force constant is: k = 200N/m, and the time the force acts is 0.4 sec, can someone determine the energy the brown block will acquire? **That is a very narrow, specific question.**
- Even if we knew the mass of the block which is pushed by the spring, can we determine its v or Ke? If we put a mass A = 0.1 Kg then a mass B of 0.2 Kg, will A acquire a speed which is double of mass B's?

The answers are very simple, too,don't require lectures. If I was right, just say so, if I am wrong just write the values of v and Ke and briefly explain, if you think it is necessary.

---

<sup>* Note:</sup>

<sup>nobody ever refers to it as [Jakob Hermann's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/newtons-second-law-of-motion-in-terms-of-momentum/15233#15233) law. Newton knew his interpretation but repudiated it</sup>

Comment: The players arm also contributes to the mass. For heavy object you might neglect this, but for light objects like ping-pong balls you can't.

Comment: Actually this is a very important question which is usually dealt with in more than half an hour of discussion in introductory mechanics courses (at least it should be).

Comment: You say [(Leonhard) Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler), but he didn't develop F=ma, that was [*Isaac Newton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton). I think your making such a massive mistake is what lead some to think this is a troll post.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Actually, it was neither Euler nor Newton. Newton used none of his calculus in his *Principia*. He intentionally wrote in an almost inscrutable geometrical style of writing; some say he did this intentionally ("it was hard for me to derive this, so it should be hard for others to read it"). Newton never wrote $F=ma$, or $F=dp/dt$. He left that to others. Euler was one of many who translated that inscrutable synthetic geometry into a more understandable form, but there were a number of others who preceded Euler.

Comment: I've removed some comments, and also edited commentary out of the question. (It's fine to edit the question to improve/clarify it in ways inspired by comments, and sometimes even fine to quote comments as needed to do that, but commentary on the question itself should not be part of the question.)

Comment: This is the last time I try to answer this question, which I have done btw, if you cared to read and understand the novel I wrote you. Yes, dimensional analysis is useful, but can be misleading: two quantities having the same dimension are not nessecarily equal. But $F∗t$ has dimension of momentum, and it is actually a *change* in momentum. This is why it carries less info, it's only a *change*. See what I wrote about solving a DE and free parameters. Again, because of this, the task you gave cannot be solved. From a push you can't find total momentum or energy, only its change.

Comment: That is, with the ammount of force and time given, the gained momentum is what you wrote, but you don't know the total, because for that you'd need its initial value. Same goes for kinetic energy. Again, see the "general formulas" I gave you, which if you cared to think about and interpret, you wouldn't have had to edit this question again. I also wrote that you get unreasonably high momentum changes, because you neglect friction and drag, which you can't do for a realistic result. For the last time, I will write the solution for the problem, neglecting friction, which you implicitly assumed.

Comment: The equation of motion of a body on a spring is $m\ddot{x}=−kx$. Solution to this is $x=A\sin(\omega_0t+\phi)$, and $A$ and $\phi$ are determined by initial conditions which you have not specified, thus they are unknown. $\omega_0=\sqrt{k/m}$. Pls substitue for yourself. From this, velocity is $\dot{x}=A\omega_0\cos(\omega_0t+\phi)$. Change in kinetic energy is $[v^2(0.4)−v^2(0)]m/2$. That's it, you cannot determine the total energy, and in this case, not even the change w/o initial velocity. Same goes for momentum. So no, even if you knew $m$, you cannot determine them w/o initial conditions.

Comment: Your last question was, whether something with two times greater mass gains twice more speed. The kinetic energy $\Delta v^2∗m/2$ gained by a body can't be more then the energy $E$ stored in the spring. Then $E=\Delta v^2∗m/2$ w/o friction, thus $\Delta v=\sqrt{2E/m}$. Then the ratio of the velocity changes of A and B is $\frac{\Delta v_A}{\Delta v_B}=\frac{\sqrt{2E/0.1}}{\sqrt{2E/0.2}}=\sqrt{0.2}$. So no, the velocity change won't be twice more, but $\sqrt{0.2}$ more. The ratio of total velocities is completely undetermined w/o initial velocities: $\frac{\Delta v_A+v_A(0)}{\Delta v_B+v_B(0)}$

Comment: I really don't know what else there is to say, but I will summarize: without knowing the initial velocity and position (or other two independent paramteres, eg. positions at two different times), you can't determine total momentum $m*v$ or total energy $v^2*m/2$, only their change. Sometimes, e.g. in case of the spring, not even that. This is because what I've written, that the equation of motion is a second order differential equation whose solution always contains two free parameters which can only be determined by two independent restraining cconditions given by the exercise.

Comment: Pls read through carefully, and if you have questions, ask them. If you are a high school student, and you don't understand differential and integral calculus, pls say so, and I will explain what I can.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a bit aggressive. Then again, so is the question.

> Euler's formula for force

It's erroneous to attribute $F=ma$ to Euler. Even though Newton never wrote $F=ma$ in his *Principia*, this statement is almost universally recognized as Newton's second law. As far as I can tell, it was Jakob Hermann who first expressed Newton's words in an algebraic statement akin to $F=ma$. But that's all an aside best left to the sister site, [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

> We know nothing of the energy that was spent, or of the energy the object will acquire.

Sure we do. There's an intimate relation between work and energy. The work-energy principle says that the change in the kinetic energy of an object is equal to the net work done on the object. Net work is given by $W=\int \vec F \cdot d\vec l$, where the force on the right hand side is the same force described by $\vec F=m\vec a$.

> Am I missing something really important, or is Euler's formula rarely of great use?

In addition to the work-energy principle, you are missing many things of great importance. And contrary to what you said, $F=ma$ is frequently of great use. Many, if not most, fields of engineering can be viewed as applied classical mechanics. Describing where $F=ma$ (and related concepts) are of exceptionally great use would require multiple college classes, plus a library full of books and technical papers, plus conferences and workshops that occur on a daily basis in college campuses and elsewhere, plus consulting tens, maybe hundreds of thousands of people worldwide who use Newtonian mechanics on a regular basis in their work. Asking where $F=ma$ is of great use is too broad of a topic for a Q&A site such as this.

While $F=ma$ is (perhaps erroneously) used as a short-and-simple stand-in for all of Newtonian mechanics, there's a lot more to classical mechanics than $F=ma$. Even in a strictly Newtonian sense, you are missing two other key concepts:

- Newton's third law of motion, which describes the behaviors of individual forces, and
- The superposition principle, which dictates that the net force on an object is the vector sum of the individual forces on an object.

Going beyond Newtonian mechanics, but staying well within the realm of classical mechanics, you are also missing (not a complete list):

- The work-energy principle, described above;
- D'Alembert's principle, which is widely used in robotics (e.g., Kane's equations of motion) to describe motions subject to constraints,
- Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics, which are Newtonian mechanics rewritten from the perspective of energy.

Finally, I suggest you watch this short (3 minute) youtube video that features a professional physicist and that describes a robot that emulates a sandfish. Count the number of times the word "force" (and related terms such as "drag") is used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rwoz4WbXxdI . This represents but one of an extremely vast number of the applications of $F=ma$.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing something very important.

$$ F(x,\dot{x},t) = m\ddot{x}(t)$$

is a differential equation that, given that we know the forces that act, completely determines what *will* happen (unless the equation has multiple possible solutions, but almost all cases of application turn out to be well-behaved), i.e. the trajectory $x(t)$ from initial conditions $x(0),\dot{x}(0)$.

So we *indeed* can know everything - even the things you claim we know nothing of, since they're just functions of $x(t)$ and its derivatives - just by solving $F = ma$.

Comment: The question is so weird that I don't know if this really answers OP's questioning.

Comment: @user77538: Well, there are things you have not specified. The equation $F = ma$ is an equation of *vectors*, and you did not tell the direction of the force. But in *principle*, this would just be an exercise in computing $x(t)$ for the ball and then computing, e.g. the energy by $\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$. In *practice*, you will find that you'll have to make some simplifying assumptions to actually be able to solve for $x(t)$, or you'll have to solve the equation numerically. But *conceptually*, there's nothing more than $F = ma$ that's needed.

Comment: What about the [Abraham-Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force)?

Answer (score 3):

**Notice** Since I have written the majority of this answer the question changed a lot, and now it's been put on hold. However, I won't erase parts of my answer which are answers for the original (ill posed) question, because other people might find it useful. I have extended it with parts though, which seem (to me) to answer the question the original changed to.

I like David Hammen's and a ACuriousMind's answers, but since this question scratches the philosophy behind classical mechanics, I can't resist writing my own line of thoughts. I will be gradually writing and updating this answer however, because I'm in the middle of exams, and don't have much time.

So, to begin with, as David Hammen pointed out, one can't ignore Newton's other three axioms and just select the second. More to come here, but for now, as a reminder, please note that Newtons laws only hold for pointlike bodies. If the spatial extent of a body cannot be neglected, it is to be treated as infinitely many, infinitely small points, and one has to treat it with methods of calculus. Now let's just jump to the second axiom.

Newton's second law of motion is actually incorrect in the form $F=ma$. First of all, it's a vectorial equation, so it should be $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=m\vec{\mathbf{a}}$. This takes care of the misunderstanding that direction isn't specified. It inherently is. The law is still incorrect in this form however, and even though Newton did not about special relativity, he wrote it in the form (to be precise what he wrote is translated algebraically as) $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=\frac{d\vec{\mathbf{p}}}{dt}$ where $\vec{\mathbf{p}}$ is the momentum, defined to be $\vec{\mathbf{p}}=m\vec{\mathbf{v}}$. This is very important since special relativity tells you that if a body has mass $m_0$ in a reference frame in which it is at rest, it has a mass $m=m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ in a reference frame from which it is seen moving with speed $v=\left|\vec{\mathbf{v}}\right|$. But since in Newton's time any achievable speed was well below lightspeed, $v^2/c^2\approx0$ thus $m(v)\approx m_0$. Hence the second law reads as \begin{equation}\vec{\mathbf{F}}=m\frac{d\vec{\mathbf{v}}}{dt}=m\vec{\mathbf{a}}=m\frac{d^2\vec{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}=m\ddot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}.\end{equation}

One should immediately ask him/herself (as you did) what this law really tells one. It is a second order differential equation that actually connets an action of the surrounding environment ($\vec{\mathbf{F}}$) with the change in motion of a body ($\ddot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}$). It also tells you that whatever the action of the sorrounding is, the change in motion is connected with it linerly, and the proportionality factor is a parameter characteristic of the pointlike body ($m$).

Firstly, this very law combined with the third law (that is a force exerted by a point on another is always attached with a reaction force equal in magnitude, opposite in direction acting on the former point, exerted by the latter point) lets you measure the proportionality factor $m$. Eg. you take a spring (doesn't matter how strong) and a billiard ball which you specify as having mass $m=1~unit$ and you put them on a table treacled with oil. Then put the ball on one end of the spring, put the object with mass to be measured on the other, and let the spring exert force on each of them. This will be the same force because of the third law (you don't even have to know how the spring behaves). By measuring how far each of them went, you can measure how many units of mass the other body had (the friction that remains despite the oil gives the error in the measurement).

**Now more deeper into your question.**

> But the most striking feature of the formula F=ma is that it doesn't say anything about the applied force, but can only measure its oucome.

In this, you are perfectly right. $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=m\vec{\mathbf{a}}$ is completely useless until you don't know what to write in the l.h.s. Newton's ingeniality lied in not only giving the relationship between the change in the state of motin and the action of the environment, but also in giving formulas about how the action looks like in specific cases (e.g. for a spring it's $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=-k\vec{\mathbf{\Delta r}}$).

This takes us to the notion of "law of force" (this is raw translation from my mother language, please write me its proper English name, and I will correct it). These are the laws that tell you what to write in place of $\vec{\mathbf{F}}$ in the case of specific interactions. E.g. in the case of a spring it is $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=-k\vec{\mathbf{\Delta r}}$. In case of gravitational interaction it is $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=-G\frac{M_1M_2}{r^2}\frac{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}{r}$ (this was another ingenious guess by Newton). Of course many of these laws are incorrect in the sense that they don't describe the full behavior of an object. E.g. you pull a string of $1~cm$ in length to a meter, and it will surely not have a linear behaviour. Pull it to a light year in lenght and it will surely be torn apart. These laws of force are mostly the results of measurements, and in many cases you cannot derive them from first principles, or you have to make guesses about the behavior of the interaction you study. E.g. in an elastic medium you may suppose that if you pull or twist it, the forces acting between two points are like there were springs between them. If you wanted to be more precise, you would have to use quantum mechanics, and directly derive the interactions between atoms, but still there would be parameters, even potentials in your equations which have been generalized from results of measurements. In physics, in the end, there's no way around using some results, even laws, acquired from measurements.

As ACuriousMind has implicitly pointed out, even until today, we haven't found any force laws that can not be written in the form \begin{equation}\vec{\mathbf{F}}=\vec{\mathbf{F}}\left(t, \vec{\mathbf{r}}(t), \dot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}(t)\right).\end{equation}

This means that the equation of motion (as we know, this is also a law of nature) can not be a differenctial equation with higher order than second. You didn't ask this, but this is also important, that specifying this differenctial equation (DE), ie. the equation of motion, is not enough to give a correct description of the motion of the object, since it's solution alway contains two free parameters (a result from the theory of DE's). These are specified by two restraining conditions, which you also have to provide by measurement or by some reasoning outside Newton's axioms. E.g. they may be intial conditions, such that the object which you study was at time $t=0$ in $\vec{\mathbf{r}}(0)=\vec{\mathbf{r}}_0$ and it had velocity $\vec{\mathbf{v}}(0)=\vec{\mathbf{v}}_0$. Two independent restraining conditions and the equation of motion are always enough to sepcify the trajectory of a body under study.

**As you can see the question is very deep, the answer spans several pages, but you asked for it, so just keep on reading.**

> - we know nothing of the energy that was spent,
> - of the energy the object will acquire;
> - we know nothing of the change of velocity of the object, and
> - we can't even be sure that the change of momentum will actually be 50, since there is a limit to the acceleration due to the max v reached by the hand/ fingertips (therefore the momentum of a ping-pong ball can be at most, say, 1 kgm/s).

Now this is absolutely not true. The basic laws are Newton's axioms, energy is derived from them (some people derive momentum from them, but I prefer taking momentum as a fundamental quantity, as Newton did). I will show these through the example you asked for.

> - F⃗ =120N for a certain time
> - t=.25sec on a body of mass (M)
> - MB=0.1Kg
>     What is the change in velocity of the body? MB=0.1

Please note that by giving this exercise you implicitly (but I think not consciously) supposed the following two simplifying guesses and conditions: you don't care about the direction of the force, which makes the calculation more easy. By not caring about direction, you also suppose that there is no restraint on the trajectory of the thrown ball, thus we don't have to care about things like just some component of the pushing force matters. E.g. if you wanted to push a train, or push a ball into a pipe, only the force component parallel with the ground and rails or in case of the ball, tube would matter. Of course this is also a simplification, since if you applied great enough force component in other directions, the pipe would break, or you would tip over the train. Secondly you supposed that the force is constant (independent of time AND place AND velocity), which I will put into use immediately. Thirdly, and most importantly, you supposed drag is neglectable, which is not, as you will see immediately.

First, the momentum. As you have seen $\vec{\mathbf{F}}=d\vec{\mathbf{p}}/dt$. which is easily inversed by integration: \begin{equation}\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t}\vec{\mathbf{F}}\left(t, \vec{\mathbf{r}}(t), \dot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}(t)\right)dt = \vec{\mathbf{p}}(t_0+\Delta t)-\vec{\mathbf{p}}(t_0)=\Delta\vec{\mathbf{p}}\end{equation} Supposing that the force is constant: \begin{equation}\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t}\vec{\mathbf{F}}\left(t, \vec{\mathbf{r}}(t), \dot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}(t)\right)dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t}\vec{\mathbf{F}}dt = \vec{\mathbf{F}}\Delta t\end{equation}

Thus $\vec{\mathbf{F}}\Delta t = \Delta\vec{\mathbf{p}}$. We don't care about directions and suppose everything is fine, so this can be considered as a scalar equation: $F\Delta t = \Delta p$. Given you example the change in momentum and thus speed (since mass is supposed not to change) will precisely be \begin{equation}120*0.25=0.1*\Delta v\end{equation} \begin{equation}\Delta v=300~m/s\end{equation} acquired from $F=ma$.

As you have pointed out in the comments (which you also have erased since then) this is an unreasonable fast ball. Let's do the calculation again without neglecting drag. The drag for relatively high Reynolds numbers ($R \geq \approx 1000$) is expressed as \begin{equation}F=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_D A,\end{equation} where $\rho$ is the density of air ($\approx 1.225~kg/m^3$), $v^2$ is the realtive speed of the object moving through it, $C_D$ is the drag coefficient ($0.47$ in case of a spherical object) and $A$ is the cross sectional area. For low Reynolds numbers (viscous fluid, slow speed, which is clearly not the case for a thrown ball), the drag is described by \begin{equation}F=-6\pi\eta r v.\end{equation} Reynolds number is written as \begin{equation}\frac{\rho}{\eta}vl,\end{equation} where $v$ is again the speed of the object, $\rho$ is air density, $\eta$ is air viscosity ($\approx 0.7978*10^{-3}~Pa\cdot s$) and $l$ is a characteristic size of the object. $R$ for a basketball with $\approx0.2~m$ radius ($\to~l\approx2*0.2$) is $R=\frac{1.225}{0.7978*10^{-3}}*0.4*v\approx v*614~s/m$. It is clearly visible that the ball basically immediately reaches $R~>1000$, so it is okay to use the formula for drag with $v^2$ in it. This gives a new equation of motion (taking the mass of the ball to be $m=0.1~kg$): \begin{equation}m\ddot{x}=120-\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_D A\end{equation}\begin{equation}\ddot{x}=1200-1.4v^2\end{equation}\begin{equation}\dot{v}=1200-1.4v^2\end{equation} Solved by WolframAlpha with initial condition $v(0)=0~m/s$, the result is: \begin{equation}v(t)=\frac{29.277e^{81.9756t}-29.277}{e^{81.9756t}+1}\end{equation} This equation of motion was valid until $0.25~s$, because after that, the $120~N$ push became zero. Substituting $0.25~s$ to get the velocity the ball reaches after leaving the thrower's hand we get \begin{equation}v\approx30~m/s,\end{equation} which is quite reasonable.

Please note, that it is right that there is a limit on the acceleration human fingers are capable of, but it was YOU who told me that the force is $120~N$ for a time $t=0.25~s$. If you wanted a more precise theory of throwing a ball, you should study biomechanics of human muscles, and than acquire reasonable force and time data from there. Basically you would have to invent the force law of a human throwing a ball, which as you have noticed, depends on some biomechanical parameters such as the max. velocity achievable by someones fingers, etc.

Energy comes now. Energy is obtained by \begin{equation} \vec{\mathbf{F}} = m\ddot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}~/\text{multiply both sides by } \vec{\mathbf{v}} \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\vec{\mathbf{F}}\vec{\mathbf{v}} = m\ddot{\vec{\mathbf{r}}}\vec{\mathbf{v}}=\dot{\vec{\mathbf{v}}}\vec{\mathbf{v}}=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{d\vec{\mathbf{v}}^2}{dt} \end{equation}\begin{equation}P = \frac{1}{2}m\frac{d\vec{\mathbf{v}}^2}{dt}\end{equation}\begin{equation}W=\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + \Delta t}Pdt = \int_{t_0}^{t_0 + \Delta t}\vec{\mathbf{F}}\vec{\mathbf{v}}dt = \frac{1}{2}m\left[\vec{\mathbf{v}}^2(t_0+\Delta t)-\vec{\mathbf{v}}^2(t_0)\right]=\Delta E_{kin}\end{equation} The change in in kinetic energy is obtained by either integrating the force multiplied by velocity $(120-0.14*v^2)*v$ form $t_0=0~s$ to $t_0+\Delta t=.25~s$, or simply by squaring the final velocity and multiplying it by $m/2$: \begin{equation}\Delta E_{kin}\approx45~J,\end{equation} but the energy spent was much more, because most of it was spent to counter friction. The total energy (work) spent is obtained by integrating only the $120~N$ part multiplied by $v(t)$: \begin{equation}W_{sum}\approx818.897~J\end{equation} Again, the energy burnt by muscles is even more, because energy conversion from glucose's chemical energy to kinetic energy is far from perfect.

I think this rather well cleans up the mess around why doesn't a ball reach enormous acceleration due to the hughe force a thrower exerts.

Comment: Nice answer. Rapid question: should Newton's second law be understood as defining a force or relating the force concept to other concepts like mass and acceleration? If you pick the latter, then how do you measure a force without relying on any axiomatic model of it (linear force-extension relationship for a spring or the weight formula for a given mass)?

Comment: @gatsu I meant the latter, i.e. the second axiom relates the concept of force to the change in the state of motion. It took me a bit of thinking to figure out the second part, though. Some physicists may disagree, but there isn't a universal definition the special cases of which are the several kinds of forces. Taking Lagrangian mechanics you could define the negative gradient of the potential energy to be the force, but this would be a vicios circle, since it is calculated from force. However the 2nd axiom gives you a way of measuring a force: $F=a/m$. I have already given a way of measuring

Comment: @gatsu mass, so that is taken care of. Let's say you also know a method to measure instantenous acceleration. Then you take a spring, put a unit mass on it, and tie the other end to the edge of a table. You also pour oil on the table. Now you pull the spring to different lengths, then let it pull the ball back, and you measure the initial acceleration immediately after releasing the ball. This way you will find the initial acceleration to be linearly correlated with the initial length. This doesn't nessecarily mean that the force throughout the motion will be linearly correlated with length

Comment: @gatsu but you suppose so, write the equation of motion, do several measurements, and find that calculated results are in good correlation with measurement. Now let's say you define a unit force to be the force causing a unit of mass having a unit of acceleration. Now, with a simple spring, you can construct a "force-o-meter". With this, you may more or less easily measure other forces.

Comment: @user3237992: It is not clear to me how to avoid circularity in your reasoning. If $F=ma$ is a proposition/hypothesis about a relationship between $F$,$m$ and $a$, then you need a way to measure both $F$ and $ma$ separately to test this proposition don't you? From your set of answers to my comment, it does seem that you use $F=ma$ as a definition of force (which is fine but we just need to acknowledge it).

Comment: @gatsu Sorry it took me so long to answer. Maybe you are right, you made me unsure. But I think that you are able to define $F,m$ and $a$ separately. I gave a way of measuring $m$, and measuring $a$ can be done. I think $F$ can be defined generally without measurement, but its concrete form can only be determined through the acceleration it causes. Only reason I'm trying to stick to my concept however is because I like mathematical axiomatisation, and defining $F$ through $ma$ would destroy its niceness. But maybe I'm wrong, I need to think more about this.

Comment: @gatsu, if you write an answer (*or if this post is edited*) just remember that OP asks: 1.) to find v and KE knowing $J = F*t$ (which is impossible), 2.) knowing F,t and m you must justify how a realistic push of 20 or 12 Kg should or could ever produce an insane speed of 300-500 m/s. That is what the question is about.

Comment: @user3237992: The force concept may roughly make sense independently of m and a. But as you say I think that to make statements about forces that are logically valid (and testable) requires more than just a loose definition. Maybe we could open a chatroom about it to not pollute this thread.

Comment: @gatsu Room created: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24751/defining-force-with-without-newtons-second-axiom

Comment: @user3237992: very good...I cannot comment though.